# DVWP does not return any items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I am using OOTB features of Sharepoint Designer 2013 to insert a web part from SharePoint list

though upon previewing it, the dataview webpart does not load

I have tried the same with other lists and am seeing the same result.

Comment: ur question is not specific to error u r getting.
first u need to insert empty data view and then between zone u need to insert data source like list or library.

Answer (score 0):

The dataview needs to be inserted between the tags

```
<zonetemplate> </zonetemplate>
```

Comment: If u solved ur query so please provide detailed answer so it will help others in future.